# Is there a way to configure SonarQube updatecenter url

Tags: sonarqube

Our security team does not allow the machine hosting SQ to access the web be it directly or through a proxy. Instead they decided to retrieve on a daily basis the `update-center.properties` file found at http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties and make it available on an internal web server on an URL such as http:///sonarqube/update-center.properties (I have to follow this decision... so please do not tell me that it's not the way you would have achieved security as it is out of my reach.)

Is there a way to configure SonarQube's update-center URL / host (version 4.5.4 LTS) ? If yes please explain how this can be achieved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is `sonar.updatecenter.url`. Default value is indeed http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties.

Comment: where can I modify this property ?I add "sonar.updatecenter.url=.." in conf/sonar.properties,but seems not work.

Comment: It should work. The effective value is displayed at startup in logs/web.log (see `web[][o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: ....`).

Comment: it works after add sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""  ,some problem with jdk